# Confused to read Json

Tags: json, titanium

I using titanium appcelerator..I had got a json to evaluate..I breaking my head to read the json values..

```
[[{"text":"hey"},{"text":"hey"},{"text":"hey"},{"text":"hey"},{"text":"hesssssssssy"},{"text":"hesssssssssy"},{"text":"hess"},{"text":"hessssy"},{"text":"hessssy"},{"text":"hesssssssssy"},{"text":"hesssssssssy"}],"13951406935634631","13951457282115774"]
```

How to read this one..

```
    var e = JSON.stringify(res);          
    var response = eval("(" + e + ")");       
    Ti.API.info('..' + response[0]);
```

I'm in at first array.. But how should i get the length of response[0]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution..

This is how i solved..

```
    for (var i = 0; i < response[0].length; i++) {
        Ti.API.info(response[0][i].text);
    }
    Ti.API.info('length..' + response[0].length);
    Ti.API.info('starttime..' + response[1]);
    Ti.API.info('Endtime..' + response[2]);
```